# Which version of Ubuntu should I use with my processor

Tags: nvidia, samsung, 13.10, cpu

I bought a laptop a while ago and I'm sort of through with Windows. I wanted to try Ubuntu but I don't know which version I should take.

I got a Samsung NP300E5A-S02NL

> It has a
>
> 1. Intel I3 2330M @2.2GHz Processor
> 2. 8GB of ram
> 3. Nvidia GeForce 520MX
> 4. a chipset Intel HD Graphics videocard

I know for windows there is a need of x64 to get full use out of your 8GB of ram, is this the same for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this useful link to know more about the differences between 32bit, 32bit pae and 64bit: [How to decide if you should use 32bit or 64bit](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-decide-if-you-should-use-32bit-or-64bit-ubuntu#.UkwVLIZdXqU).

Anyway, for systems with at least 4GB of RAM I suggest to install the 64bit version, because (as on windows) 32bit systems does not utilise more than 3GB of RAM.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i will check out the link and if i still can't find out wich or what i will post on here again

Comment: @Peppe: To be precise, Linux (or Windows) will not use any memory beyond 4 GiB of combined RAM and video memory.

Comment: I've checked the weblink, I could use the 32bit with PAE but i might aswell just use the 64bit version due to having 8gigs of ram
Thanks for the help